# DateDiff() on consecutive rows from a query using row_number()

Tags: sql-server

From this data:

```
create table #test (zone int, [date] datetime, active bit)

insert into #test select 1, '2015-05-26 09:34:19.657', 0
insert into #test select 2, '2015-05-27 10:34:24.870', 0
insert into #test select 3, '2015-05-28 11:34:24.937', 0
insert into #test select 3, '2015-05-29 12:41:33.743', 1
insert into #test select 2, '2015-05-30 09:41:38.933', 1
insert into #test select 3, '2015-06-01 08:41:39.013', 0
insert into #test select 1, '2015-06-04 11:44:42.840', 1
insert into #test select 2, '2015-06-05 19:44:42.840', 0
insert into #test select 3, '2015-06-06 16:44:42.893', 1
insert into #test select 2, '2015-06-07 15:50:15.783', 1
insert into #test select 1, '2015-06-08 06:50:55.270', 0
```

Is it possible to get the difference between the dates of consecutive rows given by the following query:

```
WITH marked AS (
  SELECT
    *,grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zone ORDER BY [date])
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zone, active ORDER BY [date])
  FROM #test with (nolock)
)
select zone, date_from = min([date]), date_to = max([date]), active
from marked
group by zone, active, grp
ORDER BY zone, min([date])
```

The purpose is to know the time during which a zone is off (field 'active' equals 0). Each record is written in the database at each status change.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Due to the fact that he can use the window-function but won't be able to use `LAG`, I would guess SQL Server 2008 (R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT zone, date, active, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY zone ORDER BY date) as rowNo
    FROM #test
)
SELECT cur.zone, cur.active as curStatus, prev.active as prevStatus, cur.date, prev.date, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,prev.date, cur.date) as diffInMinutes 
FROM cte as cur
INNER JOIN cte as prev
        ON cur.zone = prev.zone
        AND cur.rowNo-1 = prev.rowNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using sql server 2012 or newer, you can also use the `lead` function. This has the added advantage that you can supply the current time as default for zones that are currently inactive.
Example of lead:

```
select *,  LEAD([date],1,GETDATE()) over (partition by zone order by [date]) nextdate from #test
```

In the same way you can get the duration in one go by using datediff on the [Date] and lead date.

Summing the results of the durations where active = 0 the combined result for a total duration in minutes would become something like:

```
select SUM(Duration) Duration, Zone from
(
   select *, DATEDIFF(minute, [date], LEAD([date],1,GETDATE()) over (partition by zone order by [date])) Duration from #test
) z
where active = 0
group by Zone
```

Comment: I was unable to test because the function 'Lead' is not recognised by my SQL Server version.

Comment: It is supported by SQL Server 2012 and above.